# How to use a condition on listagg on Oracle query

Tags: oracle, join, listagg

I have 3 tables: table_A, table_B and table_C. Table_A has a Primary key and is referred by a foreign key from table_B. Table_C has a primary key referred by a foreign key from table_B. The design is like this:

```
T̲a̲b̲l̲e̲_̲A̲
ID_A
TextData

T̲a̲b̲l̲e̲_̲B̲:
ID_B
ID_A
ID_C

T̲a̲b̲l̲e̲ ̲C̲:
ID_C
TextData
```

the query:

```
select a.id_a,
       a.textdata,
       listagg(c.textdata, ', ') within group (order by c.id_c) data_c
from   table_a a
       inner join table_b b on (a.id_a = b.id_a)
       inner join table_c c on (b.id_c = c.id_c)
where c.textdata like :data
group by a.id_a, a.textdata;
```

I just get data from one table of c.textdata, not from listagg. If I try to using this query:

```
select a.id_a,
       a.textdata,
       listagg(c.textdata, ', ') within group (order by c.id_c) data_c
from   table_a a
       inner join table_b b on (a.id_a = b.id_a)
       inner join table_c c on (b.id_c = c.id_c)
where listagg(c.textdata, ', ') like :data
group by a.id_a, a.textdata;
```

I get an error like : **group function is not allowed here**

How to give a condition on listagg parameter, because I need the data from listagg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try wrapping your query:

```
select *
from (
      select a.id_a,
             a.textdata,
             listagg(c.textdata, ', ') within group (order by c.id_c) data_c
      from   table_a a
             inner join table_b b on (a.id_a = b.id_a)
             inner join table_c c on (b.id_c = c.id_c)
      group by a.id_a, a.textdata
     )
where data_c like :data
```

or using HAVING to apply conditions on the field built by LISTAGG:

```
select a.id_a,
       a.textdata,
       listagg(c.textdata, ', ') within group (order by c.id_c) data_c
from   table_a a
       inner join table_b b on (a.id_a = b.id_a)
       inner join table_c c on (b.id_c = c.id_c)
group by a.id_a, a.textdata
having listagg(c.textdata, ', ') within group (order by c.id_c) like :data
```

Comment: i have tried to run the query and i get the result like this : "data_c":invalid identifier

Comment: i'm sorry, i have wrong condition. thanks for your support :D